# How to write an iterative function in a recursive manner

Tags: python

I need to sum the variables in a list if they are integers and ignore if they are strings.

I have written one for the iterative function:

```
x = ['apple', 2, 'car', 4, 'free',25]

int_sum = 0 

for i in x: 
    if isinstance(i, int):
        int_sum +=i

print(int_sum)
```

I need to write the same as a recursive function, how can I do this?

Comment: Is this for a homework assignment? There is absolutely no practical reason for rewriting this as a recursive function.

Comment: A recursive solution has several problems: you risk overflowing the stack for large lists, you have the overhead of a user-defined function at each step, and unless you work with an iterator, you end up making lots of unnecessary *copies* of the list data.

Comment: Hello, it's a question for an entry level software developer interview. To be honest, I have always avoided using functions unless I have to so I am not as efficient in them as need be. plus I am still new to coding so I wasn't certain how recursive differed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
def main():
  x = ['apple', 2, 'car', 4, 'free',25]
  def f(index):
    if index >= len(x):
      return 0
    if isinstance(x[index], int):
      return f(index+1) + x[index]
    return f(index+1)
  print(f(0))
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive version of this function would look something like

```
def total(data):
    # If the remaining list is empty, no further ints to accumulate
    if not data:
        return 0

    # Process the first value in the data
    first = data[0]

    # If this first value is an integer, add it to the total
    # then recursively process the remaining data excluding this value
    if isinstance(first, int):
        return first + total(data[1:])

    # First value was not an int, discard it and process
    # the remaining data recursively
    else:
        return total(data[1:])
```

using your example

```
>>> total(['apple', 2, 'car', 4, 'free',25])
31
```

As an aside, going back to your iterative version I'd prefer to use a generator expression in this case

```
def total(data):
    return sum(i for i in data if isinstance(i, int))
```

Comment: thank you, the comments during the code where helpful

Answer (score 0):

Each invocation of the function should add one element to the sum, and then shrink the list by one and call itself to get the sum for the remainder (if any):

```
def int_sum(x):
    return (
        (x[0] if isinstance(x[0], int) else 0)
        + (int_sum(x[1:]) if x[1:] else 0)
    )


print(int_sum(['apple', 2, 'car', 4, 'free', 25]))  # 31
```